# Rails Ajax Form Submitting Twice - Need a workaround

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I know this is a really common problem, but let me explain how I got to where I am with this code.  I'm working on a Rails login form that needs to submit via Ajax in order to display a "Session Already Active" alert.  If there is no session active, I want the form to submit.  If there is, I want to show an alert.  Any ideas on a workaround?  I guess this:

```
$('form#login-form').on 'submit', (event)->
```

should be something else?

```
$('form#login-form').on 'submit', (event)->     # first submit
event.preventDefault();
$(this).off('submit') # Only do this once.
dataToSubmit = $(this).serialize();
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: $(this).attr('action'),
  data: dataToSubmit,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: (resp) ->
    console.log("success: #{resp}")
    if resp['message'] == 'OtherSessionActive'
      showAlert(resp['session_alert'])
    else
      $('form#login-form').submit()           # second submit
    return false
  error: (data) ->
    console.log("error: #{data}")
    return false
})

showAlert = (text) ->
if confirm(text) is true
flag = 1
$('input#flag').val(flag)
$('form#login-form').submit()
$('form#login-form').each ->
  this.reset()
  $(this.children[1].children[3]).val(0)
else
$('form#login-form').each ->
  this.reset()
false
```

Comment: `$('form#login-form').on 'submit', (event)-> ` function should return false in every case .....

Comment: I'm confused.  Why are you re-submitting the form if there's no session active?  The controller already had the form data from the first submit.  Why aren't you just: a) testing for an active session at the controller and then b) either performing some action using the form data or sending an error back to the client?